# Библиотека python для работы с тачскрином Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, bash, raspberry-pi

Извиняюсь за возможно неправильные формулировки, впервые работаю с unix системами.
Есть ли способ взаимодействовать с тачскрином на RPi с помощью python? Модуль экрана Waveshare 3.5.
Знаю что если запускать код из-под графической оболочки, то можно обращаться с тачем как с мышью, например с помощью модуля mouse или pynput. Но меня интересует возможность работать с тачскином, запуская .py файлы напрямую через shell (bash), без использования "рабочих столов".

Answer (score 0):

Python evdev модуль может работать с устройством напрямую. Клавиатуры, мыши, тачскрины, джостики, и возможно, бесперебойники можно читать этим модулем https://python-evdev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html

```
>>> from evdev import InputDevice, categorize, ecodes
>>> dev = InputDevice('/dev/input/event1')

>>> print(dev)
device /dev/input/event1, name "Dell Dell USB Keyboard", phys "usb-0000:00:12.1-2/input0"

>>> for event in dev.read_loop():
...     if event.type == ecodes.EV_KEY:
...         print(categorize(event))
... # pressing 'a' and holding 'space'
key event at 1337016188.396030, 30 (KEY_A), down
key event at 1337016188.492033, 30 (KEY_A), up
key event at 1337016189.772129, 57 (KEY_SPACE), down
key event at 1337016190.275396, 57 (KEY_SPACE), hold
```